# MySQL - Select IDs occurring in any 2 or more of 3 tables

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

I have 3 tables, each containing IDs. I would like to select all IDs appearing in any 2 or more of these tables. How can I achieve this in MySQL 5.7?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a union approach along with aggregation we can try:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table3
) t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  t1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table1)
, t2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table2)
, t3 AS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table3)
, comb AS (
            SELECT id FROM t1
  UNION ALL SELECT id FROM t2
  UNION ALL SELECT id FROM t3
  )
SELECT
  id
, COUNT(*) AS occ_count
FROM comb
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 1
```